# How to solve a system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

How can I solve this system of equations?

> $$ y^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$$
>
> $$ x^2 = y^3 - 3y^2 + 2y$$

Comment: Do $x,y \in \mathbb{N}  ?$

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. Your question is missing a context. Also could you edit your post to add your thoughts on this problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I removed the linear-algebra tag.  These are not linear equations.

Comment: Real solution pairs are $(0,0)$ and $(2\pm\sqrt 2, 2\pm \sqrt 2)$.

Comment: Solutions check out:  [image of graph](https://puu.sh/EKZKG.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$$

$$x^2 = y^3 - 3y^2 + 2y$$

Subtracring $(1.)$ from $(2.)$ ,

$$\begin{align}  x^2 - y^2 & = y^3 - x^3 + 3x^2 - 3y^2 + 2y-2x 
 \\  \color{#f04}{(x+y)(x-y)}& \color{#f04}{= (y-x)(y^2+x^2+xy) +3(x+y)(x-y) + 2(y-x)} \\
  \end{align}$$

If $(x-y)=0 \implies x=y$ , Which gives $\color{#39f}{x^2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x}$
, Which yields $\color{#4b9}{x =0 , 2\pm \sqrt 2}$

If $x \ne y$ , Then :

$$x+y = -(x^2 + y^2 +xy) + 3(x+y) - 2$$
$$(x^2+y^2+xy) = 2(x+y-1)$$
$$x^2 + (y-2)x + (y^2-2y+2) = 0$$

Using Quadratic formula , we have obtain the discriminant :
$$D = (y-2)^2 - 4(y^2-2y+2)$$

$$D = -3y^2 + 4y - 4 \implies \boxed{D = -3 \left(y - \frac23 \right)^2 - \frac83}$$

We can observe that $\color{#da0}{D\lt 0}$ for all values of $y$. Hence the equation has no solutions for real $x,y$.

Hence the only solutions are $(x , y) = (0,0) \,\, , (2\pm\sqrt2,2\pm\sqrt2)$

Comment: +1 but you seem to have omitted the conclusion.

Comment: Looks fine to me.